# Not even close to being a duplicate question

Tags: discussion

This turned to be a non-question because the two questions are legitimate duplicates so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The only person who thinks the Chromium question is even remotely about the game is you. Even OP of that question says "2 options", where the search result has three counting the game. It's clear that only the browser packages are the subject of discussion.

Comment: @karel well, you are ignoring the OP, my answer, the comment on your answer which was upvoted 5x more times than your answer...

Comment: Well, your entire justification for them not being duplicates is that you this the Chromium question is somehow about the difference between the game and the browser. Which it isn't. And which is what Byte's comment tells you. Here, let me say it again: The Chromium question is about the two options available in Ubuntu Software for **installing the browser**. ***Not about the game***. Now are you going to say there aren't two packages for installing Chromium browser in Ubuntu Software?

Comment: It was a duplicate after all, so I deleted my own wrong content. You can delete your own answer if you want because the issue is almost closed. I tried deleting/undeleting an 8-upvoted answer of mine, so I know that self-deletion of upvoted answers works on Meta. Then I'll delete my original question, even though I don't deserve any special consideration on this question because after all it was my fault.

Comment: @karel but [your answer on the VLC post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031293/158442) wasn't wrong, and shouldn't have been deleted. Please undelete it.